# text message blocking does not work using broadcast receiver

Tags: android

Iam creating an app for blocking incoming calls and text messages in android(jellybean).The function for blocking calls works perfectly.But when i add the functionality for blocking text messages to the same application the messages do not get blocked
My manifest file is:

```
 <receiver android:name=".CallBarring" android:permission="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE">
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000"><action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name=".SMSReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
        <intent-filter android:priority="5822">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

the oncreate method of mainActivity is:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Initialization of the button of the Main screen
    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    b2.setOnClickListener(this);
    b3=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn3);
    b3.setOnClickListener(this);
    b4=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btn4);
    b4.setOnClickListener(this);

    TextView textView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
    Context context=getApplicationContext();
    TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    String carrierName = manager.getNetworkOperatorName();
    textView.setText(carrierName);
    String tag1="calling";
    sms = new SMSReceiver();
    IntentFilter intentSMS = new IntentFilter(
            "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    intentSMS.setPriority(2147483647);
    registerReceiver(sms, intentSMS);
    String tag="messaging";
    Log.d(tag," hello!!!! started messaging activity");
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(this,SMSReceiver.class);
    // EditText edt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
    // intent.putExtra("message",(CharSequence) edt.getText().toString());
    intent1.setAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
    sendBroadcast(intent1);
    Log.d(tag,"sent intent for messaging");
```

Comment: What do you mean by blocking? Do you mean intercepting?

Comment: I mean the text message should not reach the receiver's phone